# XML Gzip and Base64 encode and store in DB

Tags: java, base64, gzipoutputstream

I was trying to Gzip and Base64 encode XML and then persist in the database.

Code:

```
    public static Base64OutputStream compressAndEncode(String file) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        String filePath = getAbsoluteFilePath("test.xml");
        String fileContent = Files.readString(Path.of(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Base64OutputStream gzipBase64 = fileGzipAndBase64(fileContent);
        LOG.info("gzipBase64: " + gzipBase64.toString());
        return gzipBase64;
    }

    public static Base64OutputStream fileGzipAndBase64(String fileContent) throws IOException {

        try {
            Base64OutputStream b64os = new Base64OutputStream(System.out);
            GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(b64os);
            gzip.write(fileContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            gzip.close();
            b64os.close();
            return b64os;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


  Base64OutputStream data = TestResourceHelper.compressAndEncode1(paymentFile);

  sql = "insert into file (xml-content) values(decode('" + data + "', 'base64'))";
```

But in the db insertion step I get below error

```
ERROR: invalid symbol "." found while decoding base64 sequence
```

However if I used hardocoded string as `data = "H4sIAAAAAAA..xftH+CWV0apGQAA"` it works

So I guess some issue with the output in the `compressAndEncode()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to invalid input in this `decode('" + data + "', 'base64')` wahere base64 data insertion into the DB column(`bytea`).

So the reson for above data issue was as missing the conversion from  `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `ByteArray`.

public static Base64OutputStream fileGzipAndBase64(String fileContent) throws IOException {

```
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   //** new-line ***
    Base64OutputStream b64os = new Base64OutputStream(System.out);
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(b64os);
    gzip.write(fileContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.close();
    b64os.close();
    String base64 = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");  //** new-line ***
    return base64;
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

}